# global binding expression for adding property to mustache based bindings

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fullstory

We are trying to leverage the [FullStory](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020828273-Getting-Started-with-FullStory)  system into our site. However, we have a TON of PII data, and we would like to avoid having the explicitly denote each individual hard coded data as PII.

I was thinking if there was a way to create a global filter for our mustache binding expressions, we could invert the need, only unmasking fields that we deem acceptable to provide to FullStory.

for example:

Full story would require me to write the following in my templates:

```
<template>
  <h1 class="fs-mask">Hello {{user.Name}}</h1>
  <h2>please checkout {{newFeatureText}}</h2>
</template>
```

I write a component that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello {{user.Name}}</h1>
  <h2>please checkout {{newFeatureText | nonPII}}</h2>
</template>
```

This way we don't accidently miss masking information in our full story recording.

Comment: I am hoping i could piggy back off of the data bindings, rather than having to do a bunch of css configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered inverting this and asking to turn on the "Private by Default" option? If there were any non-PII data you really wanted to see in your recordings you could then unmask just that data?

https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044349073-FullStory-Private-by-Default